# Can I use Php function inside mysql select statement?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to get the cit name by using getCity() function, but Unfortunately it does not works for me. Please help.

```
$sql =("
    SELECT
        distinct orders.id as 'Order Id',
        users.email,
        orders.price as 'Amount', 
        orders.at as 'Date and Time',
        '".getCity($id)."' as 'CITY'
    FROM users, orders, order_history, users_address
    WHERE
        users.id = order_history.uid
        AND orders.id = order_history.oid 
        AND orders.real = 1 AND orders.price > 1
        AND orders.payment_status = 1 AND orders.status = 1
    ORDER BY orders.id;
");
```

Comment: You can't use PHP function inside SQL query

Comment: and what is the  getCity($id)  function return??

Comment: Post your getCity function it should be return single value. if you are getting array then mysql cant understand your sql query.

Comment: In 2015 you should be using prepared statements.

Comment: Did you check the possibility to make a sub-query in your query?

Answer (score 0):

You only can use result of this function:

```
$result = getCity($id);

$sql =("
    SELECT
        distinct orders.id as 'Order Id', 
        users.email, orders.price as 'Amount', 
        orders.at as 'Date and Time',
        '$result' as 'CITY'
    FROM users, orders, order_history, users_address
    WHERE users.id = order_history.uid
        AND orders.id= order_history.oid 
        AND orders.real = 1 AND orders.price > 1
        AND orders.payment_status = 1 AND orders.status = 1
    order by orders.id;
");
```

In this case `$result` can be only string. Always the same string - for each row which you can get from DB.

If `$result` will be name of column you should put it without `'` in your query.

Comment: Dear Kampil P, thank you so much for your ans. But..

$result = getCity($id);

it only works when i assign an id to $id variable. I want to get the result for every user. their are more than 1000 user.

How is it possible?

Comment: You can build query with joins - read about it, especially `LEFT JOIN`. If you show me structure of your tables and determine what exactly you want to select, I can try help you with build this query.